# Laravel Application on Production Server not Sending Cookies

Tags: php, laravel, csrf-token

I have a Laravel application that I've been working on, and I'm trying to upload it to a production server. ***The application works perfectly on localhost.*** The upload went smoothly, and I can access the login page. However, when I try to login, it gives me a `TokenMismatchException on line 68`. I notice that my browser isn't receiving and cookies, and this causes the sessions not to be started. After data dumping some variables, I notice that the CSRF Token is being recreated on each request. I tried changing the domain in `Session.php`, but it still doesn't work.

Also, how should I format the domain if the URL is something like this: `https://asdf.apple.example` ?